# Send sms from java servlet to cell phone

Tags: java, servlets, sms

I want to create an application which send sms from java servlet to mobile device, it's my first time to make like this application.

I found many APIs that supports this feature, actually they confuse me, so I choose one tutorial and follow it,
here's the link of the tutorial  http://www.visualgsm.com/tutorial010_send_sms_java.htm
I download VisualGSM Enterprise Server (SMS Gateway) and run it, try to make the steps as mentioned, step 3 in example 2 doesn't work.

I want to know, whether I can make real testing for sending sms? Can I receive an sms on my own cell phone??

what is the best way to send sms? I really confused :(

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 ways to do this: via modem or via API service.

There are various services which provide a gateway to the carriers as a service. They are called aggregators. A few industrial grade ones are mobile messenger and ericsson other consumer grade aggregators are http://www.twilio.com/sms/.

Comment: can u tell me the steps to make it via API.

Comment: signup at twillo and follow the guides they have. What don't you get?